# Changing size of image obtained from camera explanation

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-processing

I am new to iOS and have experience with image processing coding in other languages, which I was hoping to translate into an app, however I am getting some unusual behavior which I don't understand. When I convert an image to a Data array and look at the number of elements in the array, with every new image this number changes. When I look at the specific data in the array, the values are 0-255 which matches what I would expect for a grayscale image, but I am confused why the size (or number of elements) in the data array changes. I would expect it to be held constant since I set the captureSession to 640x480. Why is this not the case? Even if it wasn't a grayscale image, I would expect the size to remain the same and not change picture to picture.

UPDATE:
I am getting the uiimage from AV, and the code is shown below. The other rest of the code not shown is just beginning the session. I basically want to turn the image into raw pixel data, which I have seen a lot of different ways to do this, but this seems like a good method. 
Relevant Code:

```
@objc func timerHandle() {
    imageView.image = uiimages
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    uiimages = sampleBuffer.image(orientation: .down, scale: 1.0)!
    print(uiimages) //output1
    let data = sampleBuffer.data()
    let newData = Array(data!)
    print(data!.count) //output2
}

extension CMSampleBuffer {
   func image(orientation: UIImageOrientation = .left, scale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {
      if let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) {
          let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer).applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [kCIInputSaturationKey:0.0])

          return UIImage(ciImage: ciImage, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
      }
      return nil
   }

   func data(orientation: UIImageOrientation = .left, scale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> Data? {
      if let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) {
          let size = self.image()?.size
          let scale = self.image()?.scale
          let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer).applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [kCIInputSaturationKey:0.0])
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size!, false, scale!)
          defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
          UIImage(ciImage: ciImage).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size!))
          guard let redraw = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
          return UIImagePNGRepresentation(redraw)
      }
      return nil
   }
}
```

At output1, when I straight print the uiimage variable I get:

```
<UIImage: 0x1c40b0ec0>, {640, 480}
```

which shows correct dimensions
at output2, when I print the count, every time captureOutput is called I get a different value:

```
225726
224474
225961
```

640x480 should give me 307,200, so why am I not getting constant numbers at least, even if the value isn't correct.

Comment: It probably would help to show some code. *"When I convert an image to a Data array and look at the number of elements...."* That may be the issue. You obviously know that different `UIImages` can have different sizes. *"...since I set the captureSession to 640x480."* This suggests you may be using AV? Hard to say without code.

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: @dfd I added the code. I am trying to get the data from the camera to do image processing on using AV, so yes I  am using AV. I use a timer to test the conversion of the UIImage by setting a UIImageView on the screen so I can verify that the CMSampleBuffer was successfully converted to a UIImage, which it does. Then in the data extension, I know I am essentially redoing the UIImage conversion (which if you notice converts it to grayscale also) and then render it and turn it into data with UIImagePNGRepresentation.

Comment: @AshishBahl I added the code.

Comment: you are under wrong assumption here. first, a pixel does not necessarily equate to a size of image. the size of the image varies in different circumstances. For example brighter areas in an image record more data than darker areas.

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran Ok, that makes sense based on the values changing significantly when I put my hand over the camera. I am now unsure how to go about image processing in the iphone though because  I have done some work with image processing and webcams, and the data obtained have always been the size of the resolution. I assumed that with the array obtained from the image, each pixel has an r, g, and b component which corresponds to the pixel, which apparently is not the case. How do you process an image if you can't be sure of the dimensions of the data?